# Block UI spinning preloader

Tags: jquery, preloader, preload, blockui, jquery-blockui

I was wondering if anyone could shed insight as to how I could add a spinning preloader (like apple uses) using the jQuery Block UI plugin. The preloader would have to spin until the AJAX content loads. Is this possible with Block UI?

Any direction would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Find a good animated throbber image off the web, like this:
[image: throbber]

Set up a hidden throbber div to show it.

```
<div id="throbber" style="display:none;">
    <img src="/img/busy.gif" />
</div>
```

Tell blockUI to use that div as the message.

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#throbber') });
```

After the ajax call completes, kill the throbber:

```
$.ajax({
    complete: function(data) {
        // kill the block on either success or error
        $.unblockUI();
    }
});
```

You can also use ajax success / error callbacks to control blockUI differently on each outcome, instead of complete.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You can add a pre-loader on your website in any style you want using this website...

http://www.preloaders.net/

Comment: thanks for the link, i was thinking a more like a custom written one using jQuery Block UI

Answer (score 2):

I've taken the answer provided by [mujimu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141613/mujimu) and fixed a slight problem with it. I have multiple usages of the "throbber" happening simultaneously. What I found was that it'd mess up and the throbber would stop working if I fired it up before an existing one had been unblocked.

This is my solution ...

```
function ReloadDetails(id) {
    $('#' + id + '_Details').block({ message: $('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>') });
    $.get(...);
}
```

This ajaxLoaderPath is provided by my cshtml to get around problems with virtual directories.

Answer (score 2):

I hate introducing another library for just one function, so I have implemented one myself, with just jQuery, JavaScript and Bootstrap 3.

When I press a button, my code adds a blocking modal to a table, does a ajax call, and waits 0.5 seconds, then unblocks, in order to show the spinning gif(because it can be too quick to notice). Thanks for @NaveedButt, I found  https://icons8.com/preloaders/ to generate a gif with the theme color of my site.

Throbber modal: (gif centered horizontally and vertically)

```
<div id="throbber" class="modal" role="dialog" style="display:none; position:relative; opacity:0.6; background-color:white;">
    <img style="margin: 0 auto;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0; bottom: 0; left:0; right:0;
                margin: auto;
                display: block;
               " src="/static/images/spinning.gif" />
</div>
```

The button:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" id="reload" class="btn btn-primary pull-right-button" style="width: 120px;">Reload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript + jQuery:

```
function block() {
    var body = $('#panel-body');
    var w = body.css("width");
    var h = body.css("height");
    var trb = $('#throbber');
    var position = body.offset(); // top and left coord, related to document

    trb.css({
        width: w,
        height: h,
        opacity: 0.7,
        position: 'absolute',
        top:        position.top,
        left:       position.left
    });
    trb.show();
}
function unblock() {
    var trb = $('#throbber');
    trb.hide();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reload').click(function(){
        block();
        $.ajax({
            type:       "GET",
            url:        "{% url 'scriptsList'%}",
            async:      false
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            unblock();
        }, 500); //wait 0.5 second to see the spinning gif

    });
});
```

The final result is:

[image]